# Why can I not call upon the property of this object? (Angular, MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I am making an angular application which uses a MongoDB database and NodeJS server.

The idea is that I make an application which for now only has a list of posts and beside that the detailed-post. The components are nicely standing next to eachother and working but I have one problem. When I try to retrieve a single post I can see via console.dir(post) that all is good and the object has been transmitted to the angular app. The problem is that when I try to use post.content I get an undefined message.

I have searched for hours but can not seem to find the cause of this. I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me. Beneath here is all the information, if you need to see something else, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

This is the post-detail.component.html where I want to display the data.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<p>Content:</p>
<h1>{{ post.content }}</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

The detail.ts file (I left out the imports)

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-post-detail',
  templateUrl: './post-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-detail.component.css']
})
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post = new Post();
  id: string;

constructor(private postService: PostService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        this.postService.getPost(this.id).then(res => {
          console.dir(res);
          console.dir(res.content);
          this.post = res;
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The post.service.ts which I am using to retrieve the actual data:

```
@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  postChanged = new Subject<Post[]>();

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private serverUrl = environment.serverUrl + '/blogPosts/'; // URL to web api
  private posts: Post[];

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  //this one DOES work
  getPosts() {
    console.log('Fetching BlogPosts from database.')
    return this.http.get(this.serverUrl, {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        this.posts = response.json() as Post[];
        return response.json() as Post[];
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error;
      });
  }

  getPost(index: string) {
    console.log('Fetching individual BlogPost from database.');
    console.log('index' + index);
    if (index == null) {
      console.log('null');
      return null;
    }
    return this.http.get(this.serverUrl + index, {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        console.dir(response.json().content);
        console.dir(response.json());
        return response.json() as Post;
      })
      .catch(error => {

        return this.handleError(error);
      });
  }
}
```

The Post model:

```
export class Post {

  private id: string;
  private _content: string;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
  public get _id(): string {
    return this.id;
  }

  public set _id(n: string) {
    this.id = n;
  }

  public get content(): string {
    return this._content;
  }

  public set content(n: string) {
    this._content = n;
  }
}
```

And I added in the Postman GET /blogPost/id and the console log as images.
Thanks!

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5XY4.png)

[Postman GET route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCq9m.png)

Comment: is there a change that `{{ post._content }}` could work ? `undefined` it means it doesn't have any value. What do you receive from the endpoint ? Btw, why do u use the naming convention `'_'` only for `_content` and not `id` ? I am not saying it's wrong, but what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: @DrNio This was a starterpack I got from my course, I did not name it myself. But as you can see in my console, the property is called "content", not "_content".

Comment: yes, i see it in the console, but before you receive it in the component (async) operation, you have a initialise it with `new Post()` which has a `_content` property. It's a bit confusing to me. And again it's an idea - i am not sure if that is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but can you please change the `_content` to `content` everywhere in the service ?

Edit: are you sure the `this.id` is correct when you call the service method ? cause if it is `null or undefined` then `return null` will be executed.

Another note is that in Postman i see the response is an array of objects (one object) at this example. Can you try `this.post = res[0];` in the component ?

Comment: I will try this, I will get back to you when it's done.

Comment: Sadly, this did not help

Answer (score 0):

```
return response.json() as Post;
```

In post.service.ts should be:

```
return response.json()[0] as Post;
```

I did not see that the object was wrapped in an array, by accessing it I was able to get it out and use it.

Comment: indeed, or you can do it in the component as i suggested, it should work - u can mark it also as an answer if you like